# AWS Sagemaker Pipeline: exec format error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to setup a training pipeline using the AWS Sagemaker Python SDK. However when the pipeline executes, it fails on the processing step with the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: exec format error
```

So far I have tried the following:

- Built a custom Docker image which uses Poetry to install my project dependencies
- Upload Docker image to AWS ECR
- Attached Docker image to my Sagemaker domain
- Passed the URI for the image to my processor when building the pipeline as follows:

```
script_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    instance_count=processing_instance_count,
    base_job_name="base-job-name",
    image_uri=image_uri,
    role=role,
    command=["python3"],
)
```

Here is my Dockerfile for reference:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    # prevents python creating .pyc files
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    # pip
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    # poetry
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1 \
    # make poetry install to this location
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    # do not ask any interactive question
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1

# prepend poetry and venv to path
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y

# install poetry - respects $POETRY_VERSION & $POETRY_HOME
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install poetry


# copy project requirement files here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY / /

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

WORKDIR /
```

Comment: What laptop are you working on? I remember running into similar issues with Docker images when I switched to an Apple M1 Pro chip and was building images locally and running them in cloud environments. Using the tag `--platform=linux/amd64` during the build step solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah that was it - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `exec format error` in Docker refers to an error when a container tries to execute a binary file incompatible with the host system.

You must rebuild the image using the corresponding target architecture if the architecture of the laptop you are working on is different.

I ran into a similar issue while working on a laptop with an Apple M1 Pro chip. My solution was to build the docker image with the `--platform=linux/amd64` tag.